# Applying the Möbius inversion formula to $f(n) = \sum_{p\mid n}g(p)$?

Tags: number-theory, summation, mobius-inversion

Is there a specific technique that exists to reducing summation over divisors to prime divisors?
Specifically I am interested in applying the Möbius inversion formula to an arithemetic function of the form
$$g(n) = \sum_{p\mid n}f(p)$$
The Möbius inversion formula states that for
$$g(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} f(d)$$
we can get
$$f(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d) g\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$$
However this definition is for the divisors of $n$. How would we get a formula including the prime divisors of $n$. Is there a formula or technique to go from $\sum_{d \mid n}$ to $\sum_{p \mid n}$?

Comment: An alternative aproach could be to extend it is define $f(d)=0$ on composite numbers $d$,
$$g(n)=\sum_{p|n}f(p) = \sum_{d|n} f(d)$$
Then invert this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that there cannot be such a formula, define arithmetic functions $f_1, f_2,$ where $f_1(n) = 1$ for all $n,$ and $f_2(n) = 1$ if $n$ is prime, $f_2(n) = 0$ if $n$ is composite. Then
$$
\sum_{p\mid n}f_1(p) = \sum_{p\mid n}f_2(p)
$$
for all $n,$ but $f_1 \ne f_2.$ So the function that creates $g$ from $f$ is not injective, and therefore it has no inverse.